# How To Access Scope Environment Options From GitLab's CI/CD Variables Settings?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So inside `settings` > `CI / CD` > `Variables` I'm able to add environmental variables and select what environment to apply them to (eg. dev vs prod). Previously these environments were part of a pull down under the `Scope` heading. After I migrated my GitLab repo over to a new one I'm no longer able to access these pull downs. Both were on paid tiers. I do confirm that different environments are setup (`Operations` > `Environments`). The red box is from my new repo. The green box is from my old repo. What step did I miss?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you provide the gitlab server version of the old and the new repo ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster they are both running on `GitLab Enterprise Edition 12.1.0-pre`. Just a quick update. Since I'm on the Silver tier, I shot an urgent email to GitLab's support team last night at 21:00. When I woke up this AM, the scope options were visible. What I don't know is if this resolution is because of GitLab support team's involvement or some other unknown factor. So unfortunately I don't have a concrete way to resolve this issue if others were to experience the same issue and arrive at this thread.

Comment: Another update. So the fix was the result of GitLab support stepping in. What happened in my case was that due to an internal issue on their end, my account wasn't flagged as being on the Silver tier even though all documents show that I was. As a result, they manually updated my account to reflect the Silver tier thus allowing me to access Scope environments.